# Photo Gallery Thumbnails Resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a photo gallery with 8 different sections and 8 links beneath it. Each link when clicked shows a gallery and hides which ever one is displaying using javascript. However since I implemented this hide/show script when I click on any gallery other than the default one, the thumbnails get chopped in half. Any ideas why that happens?

Here is a link to the gallery: http://www.searchtransparency.net/stackoverflow/photo-gallery-test.html

Thanks.

Show/Hide Code:

```
    <script>
    var gal=jQuery;
    gal.noConflict();
    gal(document).ready(
        function (){
            gal("#lobby").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#apartment-interiors").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#penthouse").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#roofdeck").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#health-club").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#garage").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#galleria").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#the-views").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
        });
</script>
<script>
function lobby()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
function apartmentinteriors()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
function penthouse()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
function roofdeck()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
function healthclub()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
function garage()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
function galleria()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
function theviews()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Gallery code:

```
<div id="gallery-lobby">
                <ul id="lobby">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/lobby/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/lobby/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/lobby/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-apartment-interiors" style="display:none;">
                <ul id="apartment-interiors">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-penthouse" style="display:none;">
                <ul id="penthouse">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/penthouse/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/penthouse/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/penthouse/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-roofdeck" style="display:none;">
                <ul id="roofdeck">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/6.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 6"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/7.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 7"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-health-club" style="display:none;">
                <ul id="health-club">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/health-club/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/health-club/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-garage" style="display:none;">
                <ul id="garage">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-galleria" style="display:none;">
                <ul id="galleria">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/galleria/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/galleria/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/galleria/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-the-views" style="display:none;">
                <ul id="the-views">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/6.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 6"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <br>

            <p align="center"><a onClick="lobby()" href="#">Lobby</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onClick="apartmentinteriors()" href="#">Apartment Interiors</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onClick="penthouse()" href="#">Penthouse</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onClick="roofdeck()" href="#">Roofdeck</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onClick="healthclub()" href="#">Health Club</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onClick="garage()" href="#">Garage</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onClick="galleria()" href="#">Galleria</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onClick="theviews()" href="#">The Views</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

1. I changed style="display:none;" on each div to style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;"
2. Then I changed the javascript

From this:

```
function lobby()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.display = 'none';
}
```

To this:

```
function lobby()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
```

This solved the issue of the thumbnails getting pushed 83px to the left.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever CSS you're using is putting a left positioning on your "thumbnails" of -83px. Try removing that CSS entry. Also it looks like you are using 1000 by 600 px images, I don't know if this is just temporary but probably not the best idea long term.

Or try:

```
.clip img{
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Tried this with no success. When I remove style="display:none;" on the containing divs the thumbnails are perfect. Why is 1000px by 600px photos a bad idea?

Comment: @WolfCat you have every image with an inline style of `left: -83px;` try removing that from some of the thumbnails and it should fix your issue. 

The common practice is to optimize a website as best as possible. Your thumbnails are full sized images that are artificially sized down in your inline styles. So they'll take longer to load and eat up more bandwith than a smaller optimized image.

Comment: I don't even see where the left: -83px; is written in the code. It seems to be automatically generated. So I'm not sure how to change it